# Change display data when use ontap in listview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In my page, I use column that has container for video view and video list view, I want to be , when I click list item, I want to change video container to selected video. I tried with setState but not change view. I used YoutubePlayerController for my video view and in my setstate, I change videoid but not working. How can I do that. Here is my code.Thanks for any example or suggetion.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';
import 'videolist.dart';
import './models/models.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart' as csv;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class DisplayVideo extends StatefulWidget {
  String id;
  @override
  DisplayVideo(this.id);
  _DisplayVideoState createState() => _DisplayVideoState();
}

class _DisplayVideoState extends State<DisplayVideo> {
  Future<List<YoutubeDetail>> _loadCSV() async {
    Map<String, String> allData = {
      'login': 'JornaldRem',
      'password': 'Aungkokolin7',
    };
    YoutubePlayerController _controller;
    final Uri url = Uri.parse(
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JornaldRem/bedtime_story/main/videoId.csv');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    csv.CsvToListConverter converter =
        new csv.CsvToListConverter(eol: '\r\n', fieldDelimiter: ',');
    List<List> listCreated = converter.convert(response.body);
    // the csv file is converted to a 2-Dimensional list
    List<YoutubeDetail> youtubeDetailList = [];
    print("Length______");
    print(listCreated.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < listCreated.length; i++) {
      YoutubeDetail temp = YoutubeDetail(
        listCreated[i][0],
        listCreated[i][1],
      );

      youtubeDetailList.add(temp);
    }
    return youtubeDetailList;
  }
  void _changevideoId(String url){
    String id= url.substring(url.length - 11);
    setState(() {
      YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: id,
      flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
        autoPlay: true,
        mute: false,
      ),
    );
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: widget.id,
      flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
        autoPlay: true,
        mute: false,
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          title: Text('Fairy Tail Video'),
          toolbarHeight: 60,
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF006666),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: YoutubePlayer(
                controller: _controller,
                liveUIColor: Colors.amber,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: _loadCSV(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<List<YoutubeDetail>> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        List<YoutubeDetail> videoDetail = snapshot.data!;
                        return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            itemCount: videoDetail.length,
                            itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                              if (index > 0) {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 80,
                                    child: DisplayVideoView(
                                        videoDetail[index].url,
                                        videoDetail[index].title),
                                  ),
                                  onTap: () =>_changevideoId(videoDetail[index].url),
                                );
                              } else {
                                return Container();
                              }
                            });
                      } else {
                        return Container();
                      }
                    }),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class DisplayVideoView extends StatelessWidget {
  String videopath;
  String title;
  DisplayVideoView(this.videopath, this.title);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String url = videopath;
    String id = url.substring(url.length - 11);
    print("Call+++");
    print(id);
    // TODO: implement build
    return Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      child: Container(
        height: 150,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: Row(children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          'https://img.youtube.com/vi/$id/mqdefault.jpg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill)),
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 14,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example provides at youtube_player_flutter package is solve your case.
Follow all the steps especially:

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: _ids.first,
      flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
        mute: false,
        autoPlay: true,
        disableDragSeek: false,
        loop: false,
        isLive: false,
        forceHD: false,
        enableCaption: true,
      ),
    )..addListener(listener);
    _idController = TextEditingController();
    _seekToController = TextEditingController();
    _videoMetaData = const YoutubeMetaData();
    _playerState = PlayerState.unknown;
  }

  void listener() {
    if (_isPlayerReady && mounted && !_controller.value.isFullScreen) {
      setState(() {
        _playerState = _controller.value.playerState;
        _videoMetaData = _controller.metadata;
      });
    }
  }
```